# Additional Gesture Recognizers on UINavigationController's back button

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't seem to find a clear answer for this.

What is the best way to add an additional gesture recognizer (i.e. UILongTapGestureRecognizer) with it's own handler to the back button of UINavigationController?

I need the original single tap behavior of the back button to work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UINavigationController put your gesture in it and then us it in your UINavigationController. You might not be a able to use the default back button but it is simple to add your own by adding your own back button to the leftBarButtonItem of UINavigation by overriding (void)pushViewController:animated to add it an giving it the relevant target methods to remove UIViewControllers from theUINavigationController stack.

If any of this is not clear just comment. Answered on a phone so could be improved.

Comment: but can I do it without replacing the navigation back button with my custom one? ideally I would like to retain the default back behavior without messing with the design. even so, can the back button have the additional long press gesture recognized while retaining it's original behavior?